# Managesieve unable to connect to server when trying to install Roundcube autoresponder with Dovecot on Ubuntu

Tags: dovecot, roundcube

In order to establish an autoresponder i'm trying to install filters through activating the plugin Managesieve in Roundcube.

Probably i'm doing something wrong, there's an errormessage in Roundcube saying 'unable to connect to server'

The mailserver and Roundcube are succesfully running, versions: Roundcube 0.9.5 / Postfix 2.11.0 / Dovecot 2.2.9 / Ubuntu 14.04.4

Roundcube errorlog is empty
Mail errorlog says:
Jul 23 16:06:01 vuyk postfix/submission/smtpd[27845]: fatal: no SASL authentication mechanisms

In /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf:

```
protocols = imap lmtp pop3 sieve
```

In 20lmtp.conf:

```
protocol lmtp {

  postmaster_address = postmaster@mydomain.com
  mail_plugins = $mail_plugins sieve
}
```

In /etc/dovecot/conf.d/20-managesieve.conf:

```
  protocols = $protocols sieve

 service managesieve-login {
  inet_listener sieve {
    port = 4190
  }
#} <- still commented, this was the problem!
```

In /etc/roundcube/main.inc.php:

```
$rcmail_config = array('managesieve');
$rcmail_config['managesieve_host'] = 'localhost';
```

In /etc/dovecot/conf.d/15-lda.conf:

```
protocol lda {
  mail_plugins = $mail_plugins quota sieve
}
```

In /etc/dovecot/conf.d/90-sieve.conf:

```
sieve = ~/.dovecot.sieve
   sieve_global_path = /var/lib/dovecot/sieve/default.sieve
   sieve_dir = ~/sieve
   sieve_global_dir = /var/lib/dovecot/sieve/
```

In usr/share/roundcube/plugins/managesieve/conf.inc.php.dist:

```
$rcmail_config['managesieve_port'] = 4190;
```

Comment: Have you configured `managesieve-login` service in the `dovecot.conf`

Comment: By checking every entry in the conf files again I noticed that there was one } still commented in /etc/dovecot/conf.d/20-managesieve.conf. If you give your suggestion as an answer, I'll accept it

Comment: `doveconf -a` shows complete config for all configurable parameters. `doveconf -n` shows parameters that differs from defaults.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to configure `managesieve` server from the `dovecot` bundle:

```
---- dovecot.conf -----
. . . . . 
service managesieve-login {
  inet_listener sieve {
    port = 4190
  }
  service_count         = 1
  process_min_avail     = 1
}
. . . . .
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not forget to open port 4190 on your firewall:

```
firewall-cmd --add-service=managesieve --zone=public
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was just

```php
$config['managesieve_usetls'] = true;
```

what's been missing after the server settings were changed to require TLS.